# Django Dictionary/Tuple iteration

Tags: python, html, django

I am working on a project for school, and am having a lot of trouble with Templates in Django.

My code is below, the first block is Python in a function, bear in mind I removed a lot for easy viewing.

```
amounts = [('None ',), ('1 1/2 oz',), ('1 oz',), ('1/2 oz',), ('1/2 ml ',), ('15 ml',), ('35 ml',), ('splash',), ('6 splashes',), ('10 dashes',), ('25 ml',), ('3 slices',)]

data = {
            'amounts': amounts,
            'ingredients': ingredients,
        }


amount1 = request.GET.get('amount1')
print(amount1)

return render(request, 'addcocktail.html', {'data': data})
```

This block is my HTML file:

```
    <select name="amount1" id="amount1">

    {% for key, value in data.items %}
        {% if key == 'amounts' %}
        {% for amount in value %}
            <option value = {{amount}}> {{ amount.0 }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    </select>
```

When I select 1 oz on the website, amount1 is printed as:

```
1
```

which is the first half of the string in the tuple: '1 oz'.

I was wondering if anyone knew what the problem here is.

Comment: `{{ amount.0 }}` is well the 0th index of `amount` so for `1 oz` it is `1`...

Comment: You're passing a tuple to the `value` argument of the `option` tag. So it gets messed up. Look at your rendered htlm code.

Comment: Abdul - the indexing is needed because the context is a list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Chillie, I solved it by removing the value = {{ amount }}, so it then takes the content that is displayed to the user as the value, the final HTML is:

```
<select name="amount1" id="amount1">

    {% for key, value in data.items %}
        {% if key == 'amounts' %}
        {% for amount in value %}
            <option> {{ amount.0 }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    </select>
```

I assume the value attribute only takes strings as an answer, so it was only taking the first half of the string.